# Change from LTR to RTL with storyboard on iOS 7

Tags: ios, ios7, storyboard, autolayout

So, i've been looking anywhere an explanation about how to implement **Mirroring** on **Storyboard's Auto Layout** - not programmatically.

I have an app that support a few languages and when i turn the language to Hebrew, for example, i have a label that change it's text to hebrew. so far so good. what i want to do next is to change the label's place like a mirror.
Can anyone help me understand how to do it on **Storyboard Auto Layout**?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some research, i found the answer:
First, you have to implement an **Internationalization**. you can follow **Ray's Wenderlich** tutorial for **Internationalization** by enter this link:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/64401/internationalization-tutorial-for-ios-2014 .

Now, on **Storyboard**, all you have to do is putting some constraints to your label:
put **trailing** and **leading** constraints to the **label** you want to reflect like a mirror when the user switch the language, and that's it.

It's much more easy then design a new **Storyboard** and you're using the elements that **Apple** gave you, so i guess it's the right way too.

Hope it helps.